# How to solve an ODE to find general and particular solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, singular-solution

Salutations, I have a problem with this ODE:
$$5y^2(y')^2+2xy(y')+x^2+4y^2-4=0$$

I tried to find a general solution through substitutions, but I haven´t seen an ODE like this before, I got complex expressions (procedure in next picture).

[My Procedure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RapSd.jpg)

So, I read about singular solutions and I tried to apply P-discriminant ($p=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$) to this ODE, but I'm not sure if the procedure is correct because I'm starting to approach these concepts and topics about ODEs and I want to understand for mathematical curiosity. I tried to find the singular solution  in this procedure:

[My procedure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9VZ3.jpg)

So, I noticed there is a relationship between general and singular solution through C-discriminant and P-discriminant, but I'm confused how to apply them to solve this ODE.

My question is:

-How would be the mathematical steps to apply to find the general and singular solution of the ODE?

I would like any guidance or starting steps or explanations to find the solutions because it's an interesting problem.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

$$5(yy')^2+2x(yy')+x^2+4y^2-4=0$$
Let $Y=y^2 \quad\to\quad Y'=2yy'$
$$5(Y')^2+4xY'+4x^2+16Y-16=0$$
$5(Y'+\frac25 x)^2-\frac45 x^2+4x^2+16Y-16=0$

Let $u=Y+\frac15 x^2 \quad\to\quad u'=Y'+\frac25 x$

$5(u')^2-\frac45 x^2+4x^2+16(u-\frac15 x^2 )-16=0$
$$5(u')^2+16u-16=0$$
This is a separable ODE, easy to solve :

Obvious particular solution :  $\quad u=1\quad\to\quad Y=1-\frac15 x^2\quad\to\quad y=\pm\sqrt{1-\frac15 x^2}$

$\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u}}=\pm\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}dx\quad\to\quad u=1-(C+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}x)^2 \quad\to\quad y=\pm\sqrt{1-(C+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}x)^2-\frac15 x^2}$
$$y(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2-\frac{4C}{\sqrt{5}}x-C^2}$$
This is equivalent to MAPLE's solution :

$y(x) =\pm \sqrt {-4+5\,c-{x}^{2}\pm 4\,\sqrt {1-c}\,x}\quad$ with relationship $\quad C=\pm\sqrt{5(1-c)}$

Comment: Hi, I'm really impressive with your procedure and I learned some tricks like $Y=y^2 \quad\to\quad Y'=2yy'$ in this kind of ODE, but I have a last doubt:

In this integration:
$$\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u}}=\pm\frac{4 dx}{\sqrt{5}}$$

The integral $\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u}}=-2\sqrt(1-u)$ the -2 doesn't affect to $\pm\frac{4x}{\sqrt(5)}$ in this procedure? because I could see that $$-2\sqrt(1-u)=\pm\frac{4x}{\sqrt(5)}$$ $$\sqrt(1-u)=-\frac{2x}{\sqrt(5)}$$.

By the way, thanks so much for your help and contribution.

Comment: Some details of the calculus :
$$\mp \frac{du}{2\sqrt{1-u}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}dx \quad\to\quad \mp\sqrt{1-u}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}x+C$$
$$\left(\mp\sqrt{1-u}\right)^2=1-u=\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}x+C\right)^2$$
$$u=1-\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}x+C\right)^2$$ Note: it is the same as $u=1-\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}x+C'\right)^2\quad$ with $C'=-C$.

Comment: By the way, The "trick" $Y=y^2$ isn't really a trick. The observation of the equation shows that changing $y$ into $-y$ doesn't change the equation. This means that the solution is in terms of $y^2$. Thus the change of function $Y=y^2$ will simplify the equation.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and I understood some details about mathematical procedures, your explanations clarified some details that I didn't think to apply before, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maple finds the following solutions, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant:
$$ \eqalign{y \left( x \right) &= \pm \sqrt {1-x^2/5}\cr
 y \left( x \right) &=\pm \sqrt {-4+5\,c-{x}^{2}\pm 4\,\sqrt {1-c
}\,x}\cr
}$$
Of course there will be restrictions on $x$ and $c$ if you want real-valued solutions.

Comment: Hi, the first equation is the singular solution and the second, the general solution, indeed, can you share the commands that you wrote in maple?, please; and another question: is there any method to solve this kind or ODE or something? Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: I just used dsolve on the differential equation.  It seems Maple used parametric methods.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I didn't remember that function, Maple is a great tool, and thanks for your contribution.